# Use Object everywhere in IOS app

Tags: ios, ios5

I want to get data while the app is loading and use this in all the application. but how can I create a object and use it everywhere in my application ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way I see is, to use the App Delegate. Perhaps, because it is the easiest way. However, the App Delegate is often abused. Some developers tend to give the App Delegate to much responsibility. Several times I have seen devs use the App Delegate as their data model. That would be considered bad design.

I say this simply as warning to not let this get out of hand. So here is one way to use an initialized object everywhere in your app:

1. Create the object in the App Delegate
2. Add getters and setters for the
   object in App Delegate
3. When you need to reference the object somewhere in your applications as the App Delegate for it using your object's getter method like this:

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)
                                     [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Singleton OO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or what I often do is create an instance of a class in the `RootViewController`.

This `RootViewController` can be accessed using delegates or through (disadvice) the use of the `UIApplication` instance icw window / single viewed application.

```
(YourAppViewController *)[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
```

You could even speed things up if you define a global variable in your .pch:

```
#define ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER ((YourAppViewController *)[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an property in your AppDelegate and loads your data in that variable.

With

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

can you access your AppDelegate from overall in your application. Therefore you can access your property and that values ;)

Hope that helps?